# How to fully close a WebRTC connection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

When I am trying to close the WebRTC connection after a call using rtc.close(), I recognize that about:webrtc-internals in Chrome and about:webrtc keep the connections listed. In Firefox, they are marked as closed, while in Chrome I could not see such a denotation.

I am asking because this seems to have a significant performance impact after some time. After having done a lot of calls, the performance is significantly impaired and webrtc-internals lists a large number of connections.

Is there anything more to closing a WebRTC connection than .close() to make the browser fully forget about the connection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630821/webrtc-internals-calling-close-with-a-reference-to-null-does-not-erase-the-clos

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630821/webrtc-internals-calling-close-with-a-reference-to-null-does-not-erase-the-clos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see the peer connection go to `ICEConnectionStateClosed` and `SignalingStateClosed`. One thing that you should do is ensure that you're stopping all local media stream tracks. If you don't, the browser will keep them open, because they aren't closed when a peer connection is closed.

[image: pc closed]

Comment: Thanks, but I still wonder: Even though all connections are supposed to be closed, Conn-Audio-1-0 still keeps being written in bold and "googActiveConnection" is true. Doesn't that mean that still some processing is taking place?

Comment: It's interesting you should say that, because I'm running into an issue where my peer connections aren't being closed properly either. I suspect this is either a chrome bug or a bug with a library that we may both happen to be using. I'll dig a little more.

Comment: In Firefox they are definitely closed. about:webrtc keeps snapshots around after close for debugging reasons. A "Clear" button is planned.