# webrtc-internals: calling close with a reference to NULL does not erase the closed link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

Even if you input directly in the console：

```
let pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
pc.close();
pc = null;
```

It will not be automatically eliminated in internal, but it can be eliminated by clicking the GC button in performance!
How can it be eliminated automatically?

Comment: this is a chrome bug, star https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825576 for updates.

Comment: oh~ thanks . is it possible to trigger a GC when memory pressure is high? Is it possible to resolve it later?

Comment: that is supposed to happen automatically. If it doesn't... there is no workaround.

Comment: Chrome bug aside, having logs not disappear immediately upon `close` is usually quite desirable to retrospectively examine calls that have ended.